# Adding Content Type To Document Library

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server

I am creating a custom list and in that trying to add an existing content type.

Below is the code used:

```
testList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

SPContentType testContentType = web.ContentTypes["TestContent"];
if (testContentType != null)
{
    testList.ContentTypes.Add(testContentType);
    testList.Update();
}
```

I am getting the below error:

> {System.ArgumentException: 0x80070057
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd)

I have the site collection Admin permission. The content type exists in the site. The content type is attached to another list also.

How to fix this?

BTW, I get this same error adding it through the UI also.

************* CONTENT TYPE XML ********************

I think something is wrong with my content type definition. I exported this using powershell.

```
ContentType ID="0x0101001CC4D99118BEC246AB8D5DF12A34B61F" Name="Volunteer" Group="Smile" Version="0"><Folder TargetName="_cts/Volunteer Documents" /><Fields><Field ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentType" Group="_Hidden" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Content Type" Sealed="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" RenderXMLUsingPattern="TRUE" PITarget="MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices" PIAttribute="ContentTypeID" Customization=""><FieldRefs><FieldRef ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" Name="ContentTypeId" /></FieldRefs><DisplayPattern><MapToContentType><Column Name="ContentTypeId" /></MapToContentType></DisplayPattern></Field><Field ID="{5f47e085-2150-41dc-b661-442f3027f552}" Name="SelectFilename" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="SelectFilename" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Select" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" AuthoringInfo="(web part connection)" HeaderImage="blank.gif" Sortable="FALSE" Customization=""><FieldRefs><FieldRef ID="{1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1}" Name="ID" /></FieldRefs><DisplayPattern><IfEqual><Expr1><GetVar Name="SelectedID" /></Expr1><Expr2><Column Name="ID" /></Expr2><Then><HTML><![CDATA[<img align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/15/images/rbsel.gif?rev=23" alt="]]></HTML><HTML>Selected</HTML><HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML></Then><Else><HTML><![CDATA[<a href="javascript:SelectField(']]></HTML><GetVar Name="View" /><HTML><![CDATA[',']]></HTML><ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE"><Column Name="ID" /></ScriptQuote><HTML><![CDATA[');return false;" onclick="javascript:SelectField(']]></HTML><GetVar Name="View" /><HTML><![CDATA[',']]></HTML><ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE"><Column Name="ID" /></ScriptQuote><HTML><![CDATA[');return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML><HTML><![CDATA[<img border="0" align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/15/images/rbunsel.gif?rev=23"  alt="]]></HTML><HTML>Normal</HTML><HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML><HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML></Else></IfEqual></DisplayPattern></Field><Field ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="FileLeafRef" Group="_Hidden" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInVersionHistory="FALSE" Type="File" DisplayName="Name" AuthoringInfo="(for use in forms)" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="LeafName" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Required="TRUE" Customization="" /><Field ID="{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}" Name="Created" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Created" Group="_Hidden" ColName="tp_Created" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Created" StorageTZ="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Customization="" /><Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" Group="_Hidden" Type="Text" DisplayName="Title" Required="FALSE" FromBaseType="TRUE" Customization="" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" /><Field ID="{28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f}" Name="Modified" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Modified" Group="_Hidden" ColName="tp_Modified" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Modified" StorageTZ="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Customization="" /><Field ID="{822c78e3-1ea9-4943-b449-57863ad33ca9}" Name="Modified_x0020_By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Modified_x0020_By" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Text" DisplayName="Document Modified By" Customization="" /><Field ID="{4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb}" Name="Created_x0020_By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Created_x0020_By" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Text" DisplayName="Document Created By" Customization=""></Field></Fields><XmlDocuments><XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms"><FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms"><Display>DocumentLibraryForm</Display><Edit>DocumentLibraryForm</Edit><New>DocumentLibraryForm</New></FormTemplates></XmlDocument></XmlDocuments></ContentType>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an issue with your Content Type. Check fields and make sure none of them has Indexing enabled.

http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/07/20/cannot-complete-this-action-error-when-adding-a-contenttype-to-a-list/

Comment: I think you are right. My content type has no fields. I will post the content type xml